# SQL Tally up value based on the day of the week

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

Here is what my table looks like

```
ID | Date
------------
13  2013-03-21 00:00:00
13  2013-03-23 00:00:00
13  2013-03-24 00:00:00
25  2013-03-21 00:00:00
25  2013-03-22 00:00:00
25  2013-03-21 00:00:00
25  2013-03-23 00:00:00
25  2013-03-28 00:00:00
25  2013-03-21 00:00:00
82  2013-03-22 00:00:00
82  2013-03-22 00:00:00
I want it to output (combine sat & sun into 'weekend'). It'll combine all the Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays, etc. and combine the values.

day | total
--------------
Friday  2
Thursday 3
Weekend 3
```

This is my query so far

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [date]) = 'Saturday' OR DATENAME(weekday, [date]) = 'Sunday' THEN 'Weekend'
    ELSE DATENAME(weekday, [date])
  END AS Day,
  COUNT(DISTINCT [id]) AS score

  FROM [table]

GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [date]) = 'Saturday' OR DATENAME(weekday, [date]) = 'Sunday' THEN 'Weekend'
    ELSE DATENAME(weekday, [date])
  END
```

Currently I can get my query to output this, but it seems like it isn't adding both thursdays or sat + sun.

```
Day | total
--------------
Friday 2
Thursday 2
Weekend 2
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please don't tag 2 different RDBMS, only tag the one you are using.

Comment: @Larnu The code is clearly SQL Server :-)

Comment: Though i agree, as a new user they should be made aware that tagging multiple RDBMS only confuses matters for those that they are asking for help from, @TimBiegeleisen .

Comment: It was a missclick. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why are you expecting `3` for Thursday? There are only 2 **`DISTINCT`** IDs that have a value for a Thursday. ID `13` (on `2013-03-21T00:00:00`) and ID `25` (on `2013-03-21T00:00:00` (x3) and `2013-03-28T00:00:00`). `2` is correct for Thursday. That's 5 rows, 2 distinct IDs.

Comment: @Larnu I am expecting 3 for Thursday, because when I just group by [date] I get a total of 3. I added some more code to the post to help clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears like what you are actually after is a distinct count of the ID and date combined. Seems like the easiest way, therefore, would be to concatenate the 2 values to make a new unique value and `COUNT` those `DISTINCT` values:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, V.[Date]) IN ('Saturday','Sunday') THEN 'Weekend' ELSE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, V.[Date]) END AS [Weekday],
       COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(ID,[date]))
FROM (VALUES (13, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-21T00:00:00')),
             (13, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-23T00:00:00')),
             (13, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-24T00:00:00')),
             (25, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-21T00:00:00')),
             (25, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-22T00:00:00')),
             (25, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-21T00:00:00')),
             (25, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-23T00:00:00')),
             (25, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-28T00:00:00')),
             (25, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-21T00:00:00')),
             (82, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-22T00:00:00')),
             (82, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-03-22T00:00:00'))) V (ID, [Date])
GROUP BY CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, V.[Date]) IN ('Saturday','Sunday') THEN 'Weekend' ELSE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, V.[Date]) END;
```

Comment: This worked for me. I just edited a bit to work with my table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
 select count(id)as Total,Day from
 (
 select id, case when Datename(weekday,dt1) IN('Saturday','Sunday') then 'Weekend' else Datename(weekday,dt1) end as 'Day' from tab
 )x

 group by Day
```

[Demo here](https://rextester.com/NVSOF18670)

Comment: Like on the other answer, the OP expects `3` for Thursday, not `5`.

Answer (score -1):

```
select Day,Count(day) cnt from (
 SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [date]) = 'Saturday' OR DATENAME(weekday, [date]) = 'Sunday' THEN 'Weekend'
    ELSE DATENAME(weekday, [date])
  END AS Day
  ,[date]

   FROM [Infinite_campus].[dbo].[AttendanceRecord]
  ) as t
  group by Day
```

Comment: This doesn't return the result set the OP wants. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f75edcad642d285d6deb12fb416c4e1)